# Changing text in setInterval in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, text, raphael

Basically I am brand new to **JavaScript**, trying to create a digital watch, I have almost got there with it, however the time just writes over itself every second, instead of replacing the previous time, this is the part of my code concerned, could you point out where I have gone wrong! Thanks

P.S: I am using the raphael library

```
setInterval(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var s = d.getSeconds();

  if (h<10){h="0"+h};
  if (m<10){m="0"+m};
  if (s<10){s="0"+s};

  time = h+":"+m+":"+s;
  var digi = paper.text(110, 250, time).attr({"font-size": 15, "fill": "#000080"});
}, 1000);
```

I have tried putting the line

```
digi.attr({'text': time});
```

In before the function closes, but this has not worked. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the old element, or just change its attribute (I think probably your update version doesn't work as you have digi as a variable enclosed with functional scope, you could try making it global scope or something. Otherwise here is one solution...

```
 var digi;
 ...
 digi && digi.remove();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en2nhk8v/)

Answer (score 0):

clear the canvas before you start to print the time.

Add this line :

paper.clear();

before the line you are printing the time.